# Fineuploader drawThumbnail with Pica

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm new to Fineuploader and using this great uploader together with Pica for image scaling. Pica works well for scaling and thumbnails.

```
scaling: {
    sendOriginal: false,
    hideScaled: false,
    sizes: [                            
        {name: "a", maxSize: 200},
        {name: "b", maxSize: 600},
        {name: "c", maxSize: 1000}
    ],
    customResizer: !qq.ios() && function(resizeInfo) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            pica.debug = console.log.bind(console),
            pica.resizeCanvas(resizeInfo.sourceCanvas, resizeInfo.targetCanvas, {}, resolve)
        })
    }
}, thumbnails: {
    customResizer: !qq.ios() && function(resizeInfo) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            pica.resizeCanvas(resizeInfo.sourceCanvas, resizeInfo.targetCanvas, {}, resolve)
        })
    }
}
```

However, I need to drawThumbnail to other places. I've tried googling all around and going through the Fineuploader's documentation, but still no luck in making Pica run with drawThumbnails.

## Fineuploader's documentation

```
drawThumbnail (id, targetContainer[, maxSize[, fromServer[, customResizer]]])
```

## My current code

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 200;
$(".frame").html(canvas);
uploader.drawThumbnail(id, canvas, 300, false);
```

It would be great if someone could guide me on modifying the current code to make drawThumbnail run with Pica, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in your question, the documentation shows how to use an alternate resizer function when using `drawThumbnail`:

```js
drawThumbnail(id, targetContainer[, maxSize[, fromServer[, customResizer]]])
```

...so, your code would look like this:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
var customResizer = function(resizeInfo) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      pica.resizeCanvas(
         resizeInfo.sourceCanvas, 
         resizeInfo.targetCanvas, 
         {}, 
         resolve
      )
   })
}
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 200;
$(".frame").html(canvas);
uploader.drawThumbnail(id, canvas, 300, false, !qq.ios() && customResizer);
```